# How to bind Dictionary<string, bool> to CheckBoxFor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dictionary, checkboxfor

I am wondering if it is somehow possible to bind the value of a Dictionary to a CheckBoxFor?

I tried to do it like this:

### View

```
@for (int c = 0; c < Model.ObjectsWithPermission[a].PermissionColumns.Count; c++)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Model.ObjectsWithPermission[a].PermissionColumns[c].Name
        </td>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.ObjectsWithPermission[a].PermissionColumns[c].Permissions.Count; i++)
        {
            <td align="center">
                @*@Html.CheckBox(permission.Key, permission.Value)*@
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => Model.ObjectsWithPermission[a].PermissionColumns[c].Permissions.ElementAt(i).Value)
        </td>
}
```

### Model

```
[Display(Name = "Groups")]
public PermissionMatrix GroupsWithPermission { get; set; }
```

**PermissionMatrix**

```
public string Name { get; set; }
public List<PermissionMatrixColumn> PermissionColumns { get; set; }
```

**PermissionMatrixColumn**

```
private void Init()
{
    //I want to bind it to these values
    Permissions = new Dictionary<string, bool>() 
    {
        {"SELECT",false},
        {"INSERT",false},
        {"UPDATE",false},
        {"ALTER",false},
        {"DELETE",false},
    };
}

public PermissionMatrixColumn(string name)
{
    Init();
    Name = name;
}

public PermissionMatrixColumn()
{
    Init();
}

public string Name { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Permissions")]
public Dictionary<string, bool> Permissions { get; set; }
```

### Controller

If I set a checkbox and submit it, the given model to my controller doesn't have this value checked (true).

```
public ViewResult Index(TableModel model)
{
```

Comment: You need to create a for loop and use an indexer instead of foreach.

Comment: First, using a `foreach` loop will not work - you need to use a `for` loop or `EditorTempate` (refer [Post an HTML Table to ADO.NET DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/post-an-html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943)

Comment: But using a `Dictionary` is a bad idea. Use a collection of a view model containing properties `string Name` (for "SELECT", "INSERT" etc) and `bool IsSelected` to bind the checkbox to

Comment: @StephenMuecke a dictionary fits perfect for the rest of the code.. :/

Comment: @Wheels73 still not working, edited my question aswell (added for loop)

Comment: Your editing data, so always create a view model to represent the data in the view (and a `Dictionary` is not a good fit). And read the link I gave you - you cannot use `ElementAt()` and you still have the outer `foreach` loop which will not work

Comment: @StephenMuecke but the outer foreach is working, it is showing me the `@item.Name`s?

Comment: No it is NOT! Read the link to understand how the `name` attributes relate to binding to your model - your `CheckBoxFor()` is generating a `name` attribute that has no relationship to the model and will not bind (because of both your `foreach` loop and the `ElementAt()`)

Comment: what is wrong with `ElementAt()`????

Comment: Again, read the link and then look at the `name` attributes you are generating

Comment: @StephenMuecke I updated my question (still not working), but to be honest I still don't know the difference between `[i]` or `ElementAt(i)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176806/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-david-walser).